# ¿A que se debe este error? Warning: mysqli_query(), (fetch_array, num_rows):: expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in,

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 function loguearDocente($user, $pass)
 {
 global $conexion;
 //$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['user']);
 //$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['pass']);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_profesores WHERE (User='".$user."' OR EMail='$user') AND Passwd='".$pass."'";
 $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); //error
 $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,MYSQLI_ASSOC); //error
 $conta = mysqli_num_rows($resultado); // error

if ( $pass == $fila["Passwd"] ) {
 //if ( $pass == $fila ["Passwd"] )
$sql2 = "SELECT User FROM users_profesores WHERE (User='".$user."' OR EMail='$user') AND Passwd='".$pass."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num_row == "1") {
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result); // Obtiene una fila de resultados como un array asociativo, numérico, o ambos
session_start();
$_SESSION["user"] = $data["User"];
echo "1";
} else {  //fin if num_row
echo "no se encuentra registro";
   }
 } else {  //fin if pass = passDB
echo "passwds no coinciden";
  } 

}
```

Comment: Este error  aparece si no hay filas afectados por la consulta. o una consulta con una sintaxis no válida generará este error.

Comment: creo que vi donde, gracias, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando la variable $conexion sin haberla inicializado, por lo que valor es NULL.

Para inicializarla debes llamar a la función [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php). Dicha función de devuelve un objeto de conexión con MySQL que es lo que las otras funciones de acceso a MySQL que te están dando error necesitan como primer parámetro.

Es decir, tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
function loguearDocente($user, $pass)
{
  global $conexion;
  $conexion = mysqli_connect(
    $direccionDelServidorMySQL,
    $nombreDeUsuarioDeMySQL,
    $contraseñaDelUsuarioDeMySQL,
    $nombreDeLaBaseDeDatos);

  if (!$conexion) {
    // $conexion sigue valiendo NULL, esto es porque ha habido
    // algún problema al conectar con MySQL.
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
  }

  ...
}
```

Por otro lado, parece que en la BD se almacenan las claves en texto plano (lo digo por la comparación `if ( $pass == $fila["Passwd"] ) {`). Eso está muy desaconsejado ya que una posible intrusión en el sistema obtendría todas las claves de usuario limpiamente con una simple consulta. Lo normal es guardarlas cifradas y a ser posible usando un poco de sal. Aqui puedes leer un artículo donde se explica un poco todo esto: A[lmacenamiento de contraseñas](http://www.forumtecnico.com/mod/page/view.php?id=86)

Comment: de acuerdo, tienes razon muchas gracias saludos